# Definition of a compound type in typescript

Tags: typescript

As a ts newbie, I am struggling to create the typescript type definition for an object that can have the following value during runtime:

```
{ "animals" :
  [
    {  
       name: "kittie",
       color: "blue"
    },
    {  
       name: "bruno",
       color: "green"
    }
  ],
  "people" :
  [
    {  
       name: "paul",
       color: "blue"
    },
    {  
       name: "carla",
       color: "green"
    }
  ]
};
```

The inner arrays could be defined as:

```
people: { name: string, color: string}[];
```

But how would I define the whole object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create 2 types/interfaces and use the interface for the inner objects inside the object's interface.

```
interface InnerObject {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}

interface OuterObject {
  animals: InnerObject[];
  people: InnerObject[];
}
```

Or if you want the keys of the `OuterObject` to be dynamic:

```
interface InnerObject {
  name: string;
  color: string;
}

interface OuterObject {
  [key: string]: InnerObject[];
}
```

Which is the same as using the built-in type `Record`:

```
Record<string, InnerObject[]>
```